# How to draw a thermometer in an android activity?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, user-interface, android-activity, 2d

I am creating a device management app. I want to show a thermometer in an activity and update the temp value with real time data. i got the real time data part, but i have no idea how to draw a thermometer. Are there any libraries i can use for my problem?

Comment: Can some one give me a help with this.

Comment: To show a visual indicator of a thermometer.

Comment: What have you done so far? What do you have in mind? Can you show us that you've put some effort towards trying to solve your problem or perhaps even state it clearly? Your question is way too generic. Also, it's probably not a good idea to keep asking for help.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42257827/1386969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no thermometer object in Android.
You will need to draw it yourself with a custom object and an onDraw method.
Or trying with multiple image and a relativelayout.

Answer (score 3):

This is Thermometer view

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Thermometer extends View {

    private float outerCircleRadius, outerRectRadius;
    private Paint outerPaint;
    private float middleCircleRadius, middleRectRadius;
    private Paint middlePaint;
    private float innerCircleRadius, innerRectRadius;
    private Paint innerPaint;
    private Paint degreePaint, graduationPaint;

    private static final int GRADUATION_TEXT_SIZE = 16; // in sp
    private static float DEGREE_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final int NB_GRADUATIONS = 8;
    public static final float MAX_TEMP = 50, MIN_TEMP = -30;
    private static final float RANGE_TEMP = 80;
    private static final int NB_GRADUATIONS_F = 8;
    private static final float MAX_TEMP_F = 120, MIN_TEMP_F = -30;
    private static final float RANGE_TEMP_F = 150;
    private int nbGraduations = NB_GRADUATIONS;
    private float maxTemp = MAX_TEMP;
    private float minTemp = MIN_TEMP;
    private float rangeTemp = RANGE_TEMP;
    private float currentTemp = MIN_TEMP;
    private Rect rect = new Rect();

    public Thermometer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context,attrs);
    }

    public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super (context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setCurrentTemp(float currentTemp) {
        if (currentTemp > maxTemp) {
            this.currentTemp = maxTemp;
        } else if (currentTemp < minTemp) {
            this.currentTemp = minTemp;
        } else {
            this.currentTemp = currentTemp;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    public float getMinTemp() {
        return minTemp;
    }

    public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Thermometer);
        outerCircleRadius = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.Thermometer_radius, 20f);
        int outerColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Thermometer_outerColor, Color.GRAY);
        int middleColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Thermometer_middleColor, Color.WHITE);
        int innerColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Thermometer_innerColor, Color.RED);

        typedArray.recycle();

        outerRectRadius = outerCircleRadius / 2;
        outerPaint = new Paint();

        outerPaint.setColor(outerColor);
        outerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        middleCircleRadius = outerCircleRadius - 5;
        middleRectRadius = outerRectRadius - 5;
        middlePaint = new Paint();
        middlePaint.setColor(middleColor);
        middlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        innerCircleRadius = middleCircleRadius - middleCircleRadius / 6;
        innerRectRadius = middleRectRadius - middleRectRadius / 6;
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setColor(innerColor);
        innerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        DEGREE_WIDTH = middleCircleRadius / 8;

        degreePaint = new Paint();
        degreePaint.setStrokeWidth(middleCircleRadius / 16);
        degreePaint.setColor(outerColor);
        degreePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        graduationPaint = new Paint();
        graduationPaint.setColor(outerColor);
        graduationPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        graduationPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        graduationPaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(GRADUATION_TEXT_SIZE, getContext()));

    }

    public void changeUnit(boolean isCelsius) {
        if (isCelsius) {
            nbGraduations = NB_GRADUATIONS;
            maxTemp = MAX_TEMP;
            minTemp = MIN_TEMP;
            rangeTemp = RANGE_TEMP;
        } else {
            nbGraduations = NB_GRADUATIONS_F;
            maxTemp = MAX_TEMP_F;
            minTemp = MIN_TEMP_F;
            rangeTemp = RANGE_TEMP_F;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int height = getHeight();
        int width = getWidth();

        int circleCenterX = width / 2;
        float circleCenterY = height - outerCircleRadius;
        float outerStartY = 0;
        float middleStartY = outerStartY + 5;


        float innerEffectStartY = middleStartY + middleRectRadius + 10;
        float innerEffectEndY = circleCenterY - outerCircleRadius - 10;
        float innerRectHeight = innerEffectEndY - innerEffectStartY;
        float innerStartY = innerEffectStartY + (maxTemp - currentTemp) / rangeTemp * innerRectHeight;

        RectF outerRect = new RectF();
        outerRect.left = circleCenterX - outerRectRadius;
        outerRect.top = outerStartY;in
        outerRect.right = circleCenterX + outerRectRadius;
        outerRect.bottom = circleCenterY;

        canvas.drawRoundRect(outerRect, outerRectRadius, outerRectRadius, outerPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, outerCircleRadius, outerPaint);

        RectF middleRect = new RectF();
        middleRect.left = circleCenterX - middleRectRadius;
        middleRect.top = middleStartY;
        middleRect.right = circleCenterX + middleRectRadius;
        middleRect.bottom = circleCenterY;

        canvas.drawRoundRect(middleRect, middleRectRadius, middleRectRadius, middlePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, middleCircleRadius, middlePaint);

        canvas.drawRect(circleCenterX - innerRectRadius, innerStartY, circleCenterX + innerRectRadius, circleCenterY, innerPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, innerCircleRadius, innerPaint);

        float tmp = innerEffectStartY;
        float startGraduation = maxTemp;
        float inc = rangeTemp / nbGraduations;

        while (tmp <= innerEffectEndY) {
            canvas.drawLine(circleCenterX - outerRectRadius - DEGREE_WIDTH, tmp, circleCenterX - outerRectRadius, tmp, degreePaint);
            String txt = ((int) startGraduation) + "°";
            graduationPaint.getTextBounds(txt, 0, txt.length(), rect);
            float textWidth = rect.width();
            float textHeight = rect.height();

            canvas.drawText(((int) startGraduation) + "°", circleCenterX - outerRectRadius - DEGREE_WIDTH - textWidth - DEGREE_WIDTH * 1.5f,
                    tmp + textHeight / 2, graduationPaint);
            tmp += (innerEffectEndY - innerEffectStartY) / nbGraduations;
            startGraduation -= inc;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: this article of [@ssaurel](https://medium.com/@ssaurel) in [medium.com](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-thermometer-application-for-android-295d6611b4f9)

If you want use library [This library](https://github.com/biansemao/ThermometerView) can help you

Sample gif

[image: gif]

Another library : [github.com](https://github.com/kofigyan/Thermometer)

Comment: You are a legend in the bad painting village. But github worked. Thank you