# How make seekbar like thermometer

Tags: android

I have customized the seek bar and its working fine, but the real problem is to draw the notched like thermometer on it which can be dynamic and takes the equal distance of that of the Seek Bar.

Example Seek Bar Max = 10
then there should be 10 segments, for which we need to draw 11 lines in equal distance so that the thumb comes exactly center to the notch.

[image]

Comment: How about a custom background drawable?

Answer (score 2):

To keep things simple you could use a seekbar with a RelativeLayout displaying a thermometer image in background.

Make sure you have a [thermometer image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7879175/22990089/5d50401e-f3b8-11e6-9d86-63ae896d70d7.png) in you drawbles folder. 
Just rotate your seekbar using **android:rotation="-90"**

```
         <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/root_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="632px"
                android:layout_height="1300px"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/thermometer1">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="1052px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="338dp"
                android:rotation="-90"
                />

        </FrameLayout>
```

**This is the result:**

[image]