# Designing thermometer in Android

Tags: android, xml, temperature, meter

Have tried many ways to design a thermometer in android but they are all suck.

The last work is using a vertical progress plus a circle.xml:

drawable\verticalprogressbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape>
     </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <clip
         android:clipOrientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="bottom">
         <shape>
             <corners android:radius="50dip"/>
             <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
             <stroke
                 android:width="1dp"
                 android:color="#000000" />
         </shape>
         <shape>
             <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
         </shape>
     </clip>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

drawable\circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

layout\activity_main.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/tempGauge"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:max="50"
            android:progress="25"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/verticalprogressbar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

What is the best way to draw a real mercury-like meter with this background:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Thermometer_CF.svg/345px-Thermometer_CF.svg.png

Comment: A simple Google search will produce a lot of results...

Comment: @frank none of them are open source:
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaad.android.thermometertrial&hl=en
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colortiger.thermo&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=androidesko.android.electronicthermometer&hl=en
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bti.tempMeter&hl=en
 http://automasys.wordpredd.com
 http://finance.yahoo.com/blogs/power-pitch/smartphone-thermometer-will-take-your-temperature-and-track-the-flu--131650064.html
 http://www.appsapk.com/thermometer/

Comment: This is free, bit it's round. mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/. This is the reference on android developers developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42257827/1386969

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout from linear to relative:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myview.MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tempGauge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/tempGauge"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:max="50"
        android:progress="25"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/verticalprogressbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Although it is not perfect, but finally looks better.
Now I need to add scales to it.